# DateRangePicker in Dropdown style bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) Date range picker with some customization 
so the div code is

```
<div id="@Model" class="float-left " style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%" >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
<span></span>
```

and i got this result

[image]

my target result is to add arrow at the right like this

[image]

Comment: [bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) `input-group-append`, [bootstrap3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-basic) `input-group-addon` oder `input-group-btn`

Comment: it is the same and make input size change with every change according to text size 


 `<div id="@Model" class="input-group-addon" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%" data-from-date="" data-to-date="" data-date-format="" data-chosen-label="">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span>
</div>`